# Spark Confluent schema registry client - Unrecognized field "schemaType"

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, schema, confluent-platform, confluent-schema-registry

I'm using the confluent-kafka-schemaregistry client in my spark application. My use case is that I want to read a JSON schema from the registry and process it in my app.

When I register the schema, I used a parameter `schemaType` with `JSON` as the value along with the `schema` param.

However, I'm facing the following exception while reading the schema in my spark application.

```
[spark-listener-group-appStatus] ERROR test.JobListener - Batch failed:com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "schemaType" (class io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.entities.Schema), not marked as ignorable (4 known properties: "version", "schema", "id", "subject"])
 at [Source: sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream@6a228f09; line: 1, column: 209] (through reference chain: io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.entities.Schema["schemaType"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException.from(UnrecognizedPropertyException.java:62)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportUnknownProperty(DeserializationContext.java:855)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer.handleUnknownProperty(StdDeserializer.java:1083)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.handleUnknownProperty(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1389)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.handleUnknownProperties(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1343)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer._deserializeUsingPropertyBased(BeanDeserializer.java:401)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.deserializeFromObjectUsingNonDefault(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1123)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:298)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:133)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3789)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2856)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.sendHttpRequest(RestService.java:221)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.httpRequest(RestService.java:265)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.getLatestVersion(RestService.java:524)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.getLatestVersion(RestService.java:516)
```

My code is :

```
val restService = new RestService("http://localhost:8081")
val valueRestResponseSchema = restService.getLatestVersion("jsontesting1")
val jsonSchema = valueRestResponseSchema.getSchema
```

Can someone please help as to how to extract just the `schema` from this payload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked! I used `restService.getLatestVersionSchemaOnly("jsontesting1")` and it picked up just the schema!
Thanks!